# Finding a function that varies between $2x$ and $2^x$

Tags: limits, functions

I am interested in finding a function $f(x,y)$ that satisfies $f(x,1) = 2x$, $\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}f(x,y) = 2^x$, and $f(1,y) = 2$ for all $y$.

Further, I wish the output in terms of $x$ to be bounded appropriately; that is, $f(x,y) \leq f(x,z)$ when $y \leq z$ and $y,z \geq 2$.

Problem is, I have no idea how to describe such a function other than stipulating its requirements.

I think this is an interesting problem, but I have had no luck in finding any research via searching, due to nitpicky rules and lack of relevant keywords. If anyone has experience in this respect or has an idea, I would greatly appreciate it! Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your rules are inconsistent.  On the one hand, $f(x,1)=2x\implies f(1,1)=2$ but on the other $f(1,y)=1\implies f(1,1)=1$.  Also, taking $x=0$ you require $\lim_{y\to \infty} f(0,y)=1$ but $f(0,y)=0$ for all $y$. so this limit is impossible.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You can use MathJax in your title too.

Comment: @lulu that is an interesting point

Comment: And similarly as to lulu's remark, if you have $0 = f(0,y)$ for all $y$, that would imply $0 = \lim_{y \to \infty} f(0,y)$, whereas you'd require the limit to be $2^0 = 1$.

Comment: @lulu You are very right. That was something I appended on as another property after a moment's thought-- clearly I should have given it more than just a moment. Fixed.

Comment: @lulu's first observation still holds.

Comment: @brian tung I thought I fixed that as well. My bad.

Comment: Post edit, your rules are still inconsistent.  Taking $x=1.5$ we have $f(1.5,1)=3$ but, for large $y$ we have $f(1.5,y)\to 2^{1.5}=2.82...$, which violates your inequality.

Comment: Problems *like* this one can be pretty interesting, but as you'll observe from @lulu's notes, the first step to making them interesting is to make sure they're not obviously unsolvable. Alas, I have no suggestions on how to do this except that ... practice makes perfect.

Comment: If you want $f$ to be increasing over $y$, one option is to replace $2x$ with $2x - C$, where 
$$
C > (\ln(4) - 2 (1 + \ln(\ln(2))))/\ln(2) \approx 0.172
$$

Comment: Ah, I really made a mess of this, didn't I. My apologies, and thank you all for being so patient. I believe that it should be all good now.

Comment: I don't know that it's particularly interesting, but $f(x, y) = 2^x - (2^x-2x)2^{1-y}$ seems to work.